# jQuery Ajax exception catcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'm stuck with a simple exception that I can't catch:

```
//myScript.js.coffee
try
  $.ajax
    async: false
    type: "GET"
    url: index_url
    success: ->
      //Do something
    error: ->
      //Do something else
    fail: ->
      //Do something else
catch e
  console.log e
```

When I try to call this Ajax with a bad url, there is an error and nothing caught it. Does any one have an idea ?

Basically I would like to test the url before calling this ajax request.

**Edit:**
I know that putting a try/catch with an asynchronous `function` is useless but it's to show that I tried different ways to catch those `exceptions` but nothing works.

Comment: you should use try catch with curly braces...

Comment: but why are you using try...catch when you're using $.ajax() ?

Comment: These is `CoffeeScript`. I don't think curly braces are required. Basically I wanted to try the url before calling the ajax request. I know it's useless to add a try catch with an asynchronous function but I don't understand why the error isn't catch directly by the ajax request (error).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
try {
    $.ajax {
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: index_url,
        success: function(data) {
            alert ("post is success");
        },
        error: function(request,error) { 
            alert(request.responseText);
            alert(error);
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

But as suggested, you can use the ajax response to do what you want depending the result...

Comment: I know, but it's not working. Those errors (due to bad url) aren't caught by the `error` or `fail` method.

Comment: check my answer, stupid problem. My mistake. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an ajax call with a bad url, the failure is written in the error function or fail function, you don't need a try catch for an ajax request because it doesn't throw any kind of errors at least in this case.

Comment: But it's not and I don't know why. Nothing is caught by the `error` or `fail` method.

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/atrifan/sb5292n2/ . How are you making the ajax call from server or from local? Meaning the page is served via http or you just opened a file - cause you might also have some cross domain problems. Also for debugin I suggest you use the dev-tools in chrome and see the network tab - if it makes any request or not

Answer (score 0):

Stupid answer...

There was an missing space before my `error` method.